# Subset relation for the power set of the Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to assess whether the below subset relation is true:
$$
\mathcal{P}(A \times B) \subseteq \{A_0 \times B_0 \mid (A_0, B_0) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)\}. 
$$
I am fairly sure that the statement is false, but I am not able to intuitively see why to the point where I can come up with a natural counterexample. The example I tried was:

> Let $A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$. Then $A \times B = \{(0,2), (1,2)\}$, and we have
> $$
> \mathcal{P}(A \times B) = \{\emptyset, \{(0,2)\}, \{(1,2)\}, A \times B \}
> $$
> and
> $$
> \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B) = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, A \} \times \{\emptyset, B\} = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset), (\emptyset, B), (\{0\}, \emptyset), (\{0\}, B), (\{1\}, \emptyset), (\{1\}, B), (A,\emptyset), (A,B) \}. 
> $$
> Notice then that
> $$
> \{A_0 \times B_0 \mid (A_0, B_0) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)\} = \{\emptyset, \{(0,2)\}, \{(1,2)\}, A \times B \}.
> $$

I think I must have done something wrong, as this came out to an equality. I'm not certain if I need to try, say, a case where $A$ and $B$ both have two elements, though it isn't clear to me why that would work and letting one of the sets be a singleton would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got equality because one of the sets is a singleton. Essentially, the issue is that not every subset of $A\times B$ is of the form $A_0\times B_0$ for some $A_0\subset A$ and $B_0\subset B$... unless either $A$ or $B$ has at most one element. Think for example about subsets of the plane.

So for a counterexample consider $A=\{1 ,2\}$, $ B=\{x,y\}$, and take the subset of $A\times B$ given by $R=\{(1,x), (2,y)\}$. Is this set of the form $A_0\times B_0$?

No. Because if $(1,x)$ and $(2,y)$ are elements of a set of the form $A_0\times B_0$, then we must have $1,2\in A_0$ and $x,y\in B_0$, so $(1,y)\in A_0\times B_0$. But this is not an element of $R$. So $R$ is not of that form, proving the inclusion does not hold.

For another, more familiar, example, take the line $x=y$ in the plane, $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, which is not of the for. $A_0\times B_0$ for subsets $A_0$ and $B_0$ of the reals.